# Is it acceptable to edit an answer if the answerer doesnt know how to implement an acceptable suggestion in a comment?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, editing-help

Suppose billybob posts an answer to a question, and it's 90% the way there in terms of forming a good complete answer but the he leaves some trailing caveat like "This won't work in scenario Y, so add something to cater for that" but suppose the OP lacks the coding ability to implement billybob's final suggestion.

Suppose also that [I] come along in the comments and say "billybob, you could add some code that uses function call X, to deal with the scenario Y you mentioned" and billybob says "yes, I totally agree, but I'm not very good at this particular flavour of the language, and I don't really know how to implement your suggestion even if I wanted to"

Supposing there is too much code to reasonably post a litany of comments telling billybob what to change in his answer and where (and running the risk that he doesn't really know what he's doing so he makes errors doing it), is it acceptable to edit his answer to include the code he agrees should be there, but doesn't know how to write himself?

Or is it better to just post another answer, acknowledge billybob's limited solution and say here's an improved version that caters for scenario Y, and upvote billybob's answer to give him some credit for the inspiration?

I get the feeling it's the latter, because if billybob isn't good enough to write the code himself, he's maybe not good enough to verify that I haven't just trashed his post, but perhaps there's a grey area where he can verify something even if he can't write it himself..

Comment: Here is a different, but related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327869/is-it-ok-for-a-newbie-to-insert-code-comments-into-code-submitted-by-an-experien. I think the answer is the same: Post your own answer, making it clear that you are expanding on the other answer.

Comment: Also related: [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/1187415): *"Don't: ... Change the code logic or functionality"*

Comment: I *like* these types of edits, as long as they are keeping with the spirit of the original answer. They certainly are keeping with the spirit of the community (collaborative editing, collecting the useful information in one place, making the Internet a better place, etc.). But not everyone agrees with me here, so your mileage may vary. I'd post an answer, but I don't want to get into yet another argument about it.

Comment: *and upvote billybob's answer to give him some credit for the inspiration* - red flag! Voting is not to reward or punish. Upvote the answer if you deem it a good enough answer. Also consider downvoting it if the answer is low quality. Consider not voting if you're not sure how to vote.

Comment: Your question is tagged [suggested-edits] and I'm not sure if you're referring to suggesting ways that billybob could edit their answer, or if you're referring to the suggested edit feature. I imagine a suggested edit incorporating these changes is unlikely to be accepted if reviewed by third parties.

Comment: @Gimby: I interpreted that as "and upvote billybob's answer because it was good enough to merit my building upon it". At least, that's what I think the OP meant by "inspiration".

Comment: Wait so even if Answerer accept your edit  it should be an other answer? my edit to someone answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16983268

Comment: @boltclock I'm suggesting that billybob makes an edit to his post. I'm making the suggestion by writing some ideas in comments. If the suggested-edits tag is misplaced, i'll remove it

Comment: @DragandDrop not in that case, you're not changing his answers logic, you're improving it but adding the code from the link in the question itself

Comment: @CodyGray it's what I thought the wiki aspect of SO was about, but I often feel that SO is conflicted on this point about editing other answers to improve them vs posting ones own

Comment: @George, didn't change op logic just because i didn't show how to call this funct. As instead of 2 list <string> it returns a Dictionary. But if it do not look like a major update to op logic it's great. I don't have to roll back the edit.

Comment: I guess the optimal solution would be to have another question (asked by the OP, billybob or yourself) about "*How to implement that suggestion in this language flavour idiomatically?*" that you then can answer. But yes, just go forward with editing billybobs answer with the remaining 10% (but don't make too substantial edits), then ask him in the comments to roll back if he doesn't like it.

Comment: @George yet, even that is not appropriate unless the editor is absolutely certain that the content being imported is licensed using a license that is compatible with CC-by-SA (probably not), or qualifies as fair use (impossible to determine beforehand as this is determined by a judge on a case-by-case basis).

Comment: @CaiusJard the wiki aspect of SO seems to be a bit crippled, possibly by design (though some SO blogs say otherwise so I'm not sure if it was intentional). I guess the theory on SE's part is that unlike Wikipedia, SE has voting and post ownership and sorts by score so the tradeoff of not being able to make major edits is that you can replace an answer entirely and wait for it to come to the top, whereas wikipedia only ever has one "answer" per topic. Personally I am not sure which system I prefer, they both have their ups and downs.

Comment: As a guy that had some of his answers ruined by editors trying to do what you're proposing - why not just make your own answer instead of changing the (accepted) answer? Because when i say "ruined" i mean "made them non-functional by `simplifying` and `tidying up`"

Comment: It's perhaps not quite the same situation.. In this case I have billybob's permission to edit his post to upgrade it, and he would also have a veto on it because we're in dialogue and agreeing on how it should be done..As an aside you could undo the edits made to your posts not least by retrieving the original versions from the edit histories?